# How ArrayList provides random access behaviour?

Tags: java, arraylist

ArrayList is simply implemented as an Object[]. I know it implements the `RandomAccess` interface, but it is only a marker interface...

So, my question is: Why/How ArrayList provides the random access feature?

EDIT 1: perhaps I should make this clearer...what I want to understand is why it is constant time to access the element while it is an Object[]?

Comment: I have updated my answer to address your question about access time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By comparing a LinkedList, an ArrayList and an Array visually should makes things easy:

**Linked list:**

```
+----+      +----+      +----+      +----+
|Head| ---> | e1 | ---> | e2 | ---> | e3 | ---> null
+----+      +----+      +----+      +----+
```

Now, let say I want to get element e2, however the linkedlist itself holds the reference of the headNode. To get to e2, I have to traverse all the way to e2 from the HeadNode. Clearly, this does not provides constant time operation as you can't access any of the elements directly without traversing through the list.

**Array:**

```
+----++----++----++----+
| e1 || e2 || e3 || e4 |  (value)
+----++----++----++----+
| 01 || 02 || 03 || 04 |  (address)
+----++----++----++----+
```

Imagine this, when you have a variable holding an array, only the address of the first element (e1) is held in the variable. The following array elements will be stored in the next available memory block. The array elements sit next to each other in a sequential sequence in memory. This makes it a constant time operation when you need to access a specific element. For example, when you want to access e3 and each memory block is 4 bytes. From the first element, move 2 blocks of memory (8 bytes) from the array reference. The key to constant time operation is: No traversing needed. It just has to calculate how many bytes to shift from current location according to size of each block and number of blocks to move (indicated by array index). In Java, when you try to shift beyond the bounds of the allocated memory for the array, it gives you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**ArrayList:**

Arraylist uses the same idea of an array. It will allocate a size of 10 initially. When it needs to grow (more elements added for instance), it creates a new array with added length for storage. Since the storage of the data is by array, the operation time will be same as array (i.e. constant time).

Comment: And how to know e3 is in  03 in Array?  
Assume ArrayList does not implement RandomAccess - does it mean lookup of an element won't be O(n) ?
If searching is the whole point - how does RandomAccess contributes to it?

Comment: @ArnabDutta If you don't understand the given solution, I don't think you should go around doing a down-voting spree on people's answer.

Comment: @ArnabDutta OP did not ask about how implementing RadomAccess affects the efficiency, OP asked ***I want to understand is why it is constant time to access the element***.

Comment: the OP asked why it is constant time to access the element - u sud have said:. 1) Its constant only if you know the index and here is why..then ur explanation Or 2) If you want to find THE element unaware of its index then its linear Or 3) if you have the base address or reference of Array you can access its nth element in constant time..here is why..then ur explanation...Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Elements of an `ArrayList` can be accessed **randomly**, i.e. you are free to choose an index at any time to get an element that is in the list:

```
myList.get(3);
myList.get(1);
myList.get(5);
```

The `ArrayList`'s method to `get()` an element is implemented as:

```
public E get(int index) {
    rangeCheck(index);

    return elementData(index);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
E elementData(int index) {
    return (E) elementData[index];
}
```

To access a single element in an array by index, you need constant time. No matter how many elements are in the (array-based) list, you can always get your entry in the same time. It does not matter whether the element is at the beginning, in the middle or at the end of your list.

The opposite is **sequential access**, e.g. used in a `LinkedList`, where each element contains a reference to the next item in list. You cannot access elements randomly here, but you have to iterate through all prior items to reach your target elements:

```
public E get(int index) {
    checkElementIndex(index);
    return node(index).item;
}

Node<E> node(int index) {
    // assert isElementIndex(index);

    if (index < (size >> 1)) {
        Node<E> x = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)
            x = x.next;
        return x;
    } else {
        Node<E> x = last;
        for (int i = size - 1; i > index; i--)
            x = x.prev;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Here your access cost are dependent on the length of the list and the number of items in the list. Elements at the beginning of the list can be accessed faster, since the path to reach them is shorter. To access an element in the middle or at the end of the list is more costly, since you have to traverse all the other elements sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

> Why

Because that's one of the reasons you use an `ArrayList`, because you want constant-time access to the elements. So `ArrayList` has the marker `RandomAccess` to tell you that that's what it provides. If you didn't need that, you might use a `LinkedList` instead, which *doesn't* provide constant-time access but doesn't have to do the occasional big reallocations `ArrayList` has to do.

> How

By using an array under the covers. Arrays provide constant-time access, so...

Answer (score 1):

As you said, `RandomAccess` is purely a marker interface. By adding it to a collection class, one indicates (basically) that `get(int)` is implemented in constant time.

`ArrayList` does that because it litterarly is one memory access to get a value from a specific position.

Answer (score 0):

An array is by definition a random-access data structure. An array has fixed offsets for each elements. If I wanted to access the `n`-th element of an array, I could simply access the memory address `<base offset> + n * <element size>`. There is no iteration required. An `ArrayList` is a `List`-implementation that is internally backed by an array such that it inherits this property. Whenever the backing array of an `ArrayList` cannot fit its elements any more, the `ArrayList` copies all elements into a new array. This is why a `LinkedList` can be more efficient when collecting an unknown number of elements. For this advantage, one cannot access an element by computing a fixed index any more.

The `RandomAccess` marker interface signals random accessability to users of this list to allow for implementing efficient algorithms if random-access is required. A `LinkedList`, for example, exposes the same interface as an `ArrayList`. A sorting algorithm that requires random-access but does never change the size of a list would then rather copy the elements of a non-randomly-accessible list into a more efficient data structure while sorting. It can then rather iterate the non-randomly-accessible list in a single pass-through for filling the list with the sorted elements.

Answer (score 0):

> In computer science, random access (more precisely and more generally called direct access) is the ability to access an item of data at any given coordinates in a population of addressable. Wikipedia

The `ArrayList` provide API to access any element using method `get(int)`.

The `int` is the index of item in `Object[]`.

This method allow you to access item randomly (at will). The opposite is sequential access (`LinkedList`) that you must move through the items of structure.