# What basically is RandomAccess? Why we use RandomAccess?

Tags: java, collections

I was studying collections in java in between I got stuck a point that some classes like ArrayList implements **RandomAccess** too while some classes don't. I want to know that why this interface is implemented and what its benefit? What would happen if I use this Interface in my class?

Comment: RandomAccess is an interface that indicates that a datastructure has fast retrieval time. In the case of an ArrayList, if we call ArrayList.get(x), the time it takes to get the element at position x is really fast (O(1) runtime). Another example would be the LinkedList, which does not implement RandomAccess. If we called LinkedList.get(x), it would take a considerably longer time to retrieve that element (O(n) runtime).

Comment: Some lists can be efficiently accessed random like using `get` and some more more efficient to be iterated over. By implementing RandomAccess it lets the JDK know it should use `get` where possible.

Comment: It provides the fast access from array list. Please refer this for  more...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758929/how-arraylist-provides-random-access-behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Random Access List vs Sequential List

Random Access List is a list where you can access any random data in a constant and a faster pace whereas sequential list is where you have to iterate sequentially through all the item before it, to access any particular item.

As in the below graphical image, you can see that in first example, if you want to access 9, you can directly get the values using index whereas in the second image, the data **can not** be accessed randomly and needs to be iterated through `23 -> 3 -> 17 -> 9` or `42 -> 9` and hence time in accessing any value in the second case is not constant and differs for each value.

[image]

> Why RandomAccess interface is implemented?

Introduced as part of JDK 1.4, it is a marker interface which indicates that the class implementing it takes constant and fast time in accessing any random data in list.

> What is the benefit?

Any implementation of the algorithm can check if the current list is a child of Random Access and accordingly ensure the best performance for random access or sequential access.

Below is one great example from one blog which explains one of the usage in a great way:

```
Object o;
if (listObject instanceof RandomAccess)
{
  for (int i=0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++)
  {
    o = list.get(i); // directly get the object as list implements Random access
    //do something with object o
  }

}
else
{
  Iterator itr = list.iterator();
  for (int i=0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++)
  {
    o = itr.next(); // Use iterator to get values sequentially as random access 
                    //  is not fast for this list and hence does not implement RandomAccess
    //do something with object o

  }
}
```

> What would happen if I use this Interface in my class?

Same will happen as happens when you implement any other marker interface. It just gives an indication to other class as what can be expected from the class implementing it.

You can also refer [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) to understand more about it.

Comment: Thank you Aman, this answer has resolved my many queries, can you explain that why these marker interfaces are only declared not defined means these classes are empty why?

Comment: @AsheeshSahu Because these interfaces are just to give indication (mark the classes) as what can be expected from them like Serializable for classes that can be serialized, Clonable for the classes that can be cloned and Random access for the classes that provide fast and constant random access to the list

Answer (score 3):

`RandomAccess` is a *marker interface*. It doesn't have any methods in it. 
Its marks `ArrayList` to show that it supports random access of any value in `O(1)` given index.

`LinkedList`, on the other hand, ***doesn't*** provide `O(1)` random access to its elements because its backed by a doubly linked list (hence `O(n)` random access complexity). Hence it doesn't make sense to use `RandomAccess` for `LinkedList`. Same reasoning can be given to other `Collection` classes that doesn't *implement* `RandomAccess`.

> I want to know that why this interface is implemented and what its
>   benefit?

**Java collection framework uses this interface to *optimize performance*.**

*Straight out of docs:*

> As a rule of thumb, a List implementation should implement this
>   interface if, for typical instances of the class, this loop:
>
> ```
>  for (int i=0, n=list.size(); i < n; i++)
>      list.get(i);
> ```
>
> runs faster than this loop:
>
> ```
>  for (Iterator i=list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
>      i.next();
> ```

Also see [this javadoc here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) which explains it beautifully.

Comment: Thank you Shanu,  can you explain that why these marker interfaces are only declared not defined means these classes are empty why?

Comment: @AsheeshSahu They define a `type` which can later be checked for an object and then a random access will indicate that the particular object has indexed based access. otherwise to get any element you will have to scan the structure from the beginning.